# Can't connect to any ports of ASUS Chromebook Flip?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, python, chromebook

I have recently been playing around with my asus chromebook flip (dev mode, crouton, chromebrew) and have run into a problem. I can not connect to any of its ports through through the local wifi network. I tried to run `ncat -l 8000` and `python3 -m http.server` through chromebrew, and even tried to ssh into it (i have ssh enabled) to no avail. In all cases I can connect perfectly fine on the chromebook itself through localhost but it always hangs when I connect from another device and then times out.

*EDIT:* and yes I've tried a restart

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the Chromebook's firewall rules:

https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Running-servers-in-crouton

Comment: Thanks, would this apply though, given that I'm not actually running the server in crouton but within chrome OS itself in the built in terminal?

Comment: I'd say it does apply.  Iptables alters firewall rules in the kernel and there's only one running kernel.  You don't need Crouton installed to test this since the iptables command is built in.  Just run in crosh "sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT"